# Spring quartz thread pool count is not changed

Tags: spring-boot, threadpool, quartz

I have spring boot application and i'm using quartz to manage jobs.
I configured quartz in application.properties file but the thread number is not changed (you can see in logs it remains 10).
In the pom i removed here some un-context dependencies.

**pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Spring Boot app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.9</version>
        </dependency>   
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.overwrite-existing-jobs=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20
```

**logs:**

```
2021-12-29 15:02:17.611  INFO 25563 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'schedulerFactoryBean' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

Comment: Are you using spring-boot-starter-quartz ?

Comment: Also I hope your properties file name is "application.properties" and not "application.properies"

Comment: @Shailendra, I'm using spring-boot-starter-quartz and i fixed here the properties file name. I added my pom for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your configuration on spring-boot 2.6.0 and it works fine as can be seen below. By default the thread pool size is 10 if you use spring-boot-starter-quartz without any additional configuration and it looks like the configuration is not getting picked so please check if your properties file name is correct ( in the question you have named it `application.properies` )

**application.properties**

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
spring.quartz.overwrite-existing-jobs=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20
```

Here is the logs output

```
2021-12-29 20:23:10.231  INFO 36936 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 20 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is not clustered.
```

**Update**

The actual configuration work happens in the `QuartzAutoConfiguration` class where the properties read by Spring are injected. You can verify what properties are being read for quartz and injected by putting a breakpoint in a debugger ( I am using Eclipse). As can be seen - there are 2 properties one of which is related to thread count which has been read as 20 and is available for being injected into Quartz configuration.

[image]

Comment: As i wrote before- i only have typo in properties file here and it still does not work for me.

Comment: Check my updated info.